# Draw Graph in Blackberry

Tags: api, blackberry, charts

i want to create one app which draw different charts like pie chart, line chart, mixed chart etc.
Is the any API available to do so.If yes then please give me link.
And of no then is there any alternative for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RIM have a knowledge base article about drawing graph fields:

http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800345/How_To_-_Create_graph_fields.html?nodeid=1889634&vernum=0

This shows how to create different tyes of graphs such as pie, line, bar.

Comment: Thanks for helping me.Another one is http://www.artfulbits.com/products/blackberry/aicharts.aspx but it is paid.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, there is no such chart drawing BB APIs right out of the box. So you should create your own custom `ChartField` by extending `Field`. Override [`Field.paint(Graphics graphics)`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#paint%28net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics%29) to draw whatever you need. [`Graphics`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Graphics.html) API offers a lot of drawing methods, so it is definitely doable.